# Issue with shiro page redirection

Tags: java, shiro

ini file is like

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.html
authc.successUrl = /index.html
authc.usernameParam = j_username
authc.passwordParam = j_password

[users]
root = secret, admin

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
/login.html = anon, roles[admin]
/index.html = authc, roles[admin]
```

when i try to hit the index.html I am getting the below error

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /shiro-example/login.jsp. Reason:

    /shiro-example/login.jsp
Powered by Jetty://
```

my login.html file is like

```
<form name="loginform" action="" method="post" >

        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="j_username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="j_password">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**
https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-FormbasedLogin

Sorry I didn't look close enough at your config.
use:

`[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login.html`

This way the loginUrl is set on any filter that is attempting to issue the redirect